# MS Access 2016 left join creating duplicate records

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join, ms-access-2016

I'm new to MS Access and need to add the Group Name field from table 2 to table 1 (see below).

Table 1 lists all invoice line item transactions.  Table 2 lists pricing categories by location and boat length.  The group name field in table 2 must match the location code in table 1 and the boat length from table 1 must fall between the min and max lengths from table 2.

I created a query with a left join and used the expression builder to make sure the group name pulled into table 1 meets the length requirements in table 2.

```
SELECT 
    q_Step2_AMR.*, 
    IIf(
        [HS Boat Length]<=[t_BLG]![Max] And [HS Boat Length]>=[t_BLG]![Min],
        [t_BLG]![Group Name],
        "test"
    ) AS [Local Boat Length Group] 
FROM q_Step2_AMR 
LEFT JOIN t_BLG ON q_Step2_AMR.[Location Code] = t_BLG.[Location Code]
```

The problem is it creates duplicate records for each record from table 1 for every time there is a location code in table 2 that matches the location code in a record from table 1.

[image]

Comment: Please show us your current query, as text (not image).

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for.  In my previous example the query q_Step2_AMR is table 1 and t_BLG is table 2.   I'm trying to use Access functions and not SQL to solve the problem.  SELECT q_Step2_AMR.*, IIf([HS Boat Length]<=[t_BLG]![Max] And [HS Boat Length]>=[t_BLG]![Min],[t_BLG]![Group Name],"test") AS [Local Boat Length Group]
FROM q_Step2_AMR LEFT JOIN t_BLG ON q_Step2_AMR.[Location Code] = t_BLG.[Location Code];

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64054979/edit) to add this important piece of information.

Comment: You seem to want to "align" the rows. This is not an easy task in MS Access. You might want to consider switching to a more fully-featured database...

Answer (score 0):

The query results are due to Cartesian relation of records. Use a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT q_Step2_AMR.*, t_BLG.[Group Name]
FROM q_Step2_AMR 
LEFT JOIN t_BLG ON q_Step2_AMR.[Location Code] = t_BLG.[Location Code]
WHERE [HS Boat Length] BETWEEN [Min] AND [Max];
```

Be aware, query involving Cartesian relation can perform slowly with large dataset.

Strongly advise not to use reserved words such as Min and Max as names for anything. Also better not to use spaces in naming convention.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  The resulting query initially was missing records where the boat length field is blank, but I figured out a work around.

Comment: If field is null, can use either Nz() or IIf() function to provide a value such as 0. If answer resolved issue, please mark accepted.